# Trying to split array into specified amount of subarrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm writing a function that takes an array and a number parameter and returns the number amount of arrays split from the given array. So the call chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2); should return [a,b] [c,d]. My code is returning [a,c] [b,d]. It should be an easy solution, but I still can't figure out.

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
// Break it up.

var newarr=[];
var amount=0;
if(arr.length%2===0)
{
  amount=arr.length/size;
}
else
amount=(arr.length/size)+1;
console.log(amount);
for(i=0;i<amount;i++)
{
  newarr[i]=[];
}
console.log(newarr);
for(z=0;z<arr.length;z=z+size)
{

  for(x=0;x<size;x++)
    {
      newarr[x].push(arr[z+x]);

    }


   }
  console.log(newarr);
   }

  chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);
```

Also, if you see bad syntax please correct me, I'm used to writing Java. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Run over all the items in the array, and whenever the index % size is 0, add another sub array, then push the item to the last sub array.

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var chunks = [];
  
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {    
    if(i % size === 0) {
      chunks.push([]);
    }
    
    chunks[chunks.length - 1].push(arr[i]);
  }
  
  return chunks;
}

console.log('Size 2', JSON.stringify(chunkArrayInGroups(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2)));
console.log('Size 3', JSON.stringify(chunkArrayInGroups(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 3)));
console.log('Size 4', JSON.stringify(chunkArrayInGroups(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 4)));
console.log('Size 6', JSON.stringify(chunkArrayInGroups(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 6)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Array.slice method together with the loop to chunk an array:

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  let i,j,res = [];
  for (i=0,j=arr.length; i<j; i+=size) {
    res.push(arr.slice(i,i+size));
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from `newarr[x].push(arr[z+x]);`.

Each time the second loop runs, it adds 1 letter to the first array inside `newarr` and 1 letter to the second array inside `newarr`.

This is because `x` inside the loop (in the case of `size` = 2), starts as 0 (the first array) and then becomes 1 (the second array).

To fix this problem:
`newarr[x].push(arr[z+x]);` should be changed to `newarr[z/size].push(arr[z+x]);`

Answer (score 0):

Beside the given answers, you could use another approach with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and check if you need a new array for a new chunk.

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(array, size) {
    return array.reduce(function(r, a, i, aa) {
        i % Math.ceil(aa.length / size) || r.push([]);
        r[r.length - 1].push(a);
        return r;
    }, []);
}

console.log(chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], 3));
```

Comment: This returns `[ [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ], [ 'd' ] ]` if the second parameter is `3`.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my solution;

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(a,n){
  return n > 0 ? n <= a.length ? a.reduce((r,e,i) => (r[Math.floor(n*i/a.length)].push(e),r), Array(n).fill().map(_ => [])) : a : a;
}

var a      = ["a", "b", "c", "d","e"],
    n      = 3;
    result = chunkArrayInGroups(a,n);
console.log(result);
```